Sheaf of pullback bundles
Suppose $f: N \to M$ is a (smooth/holomorphic) map, where $M,N$ are (smooth/complex) manifolds (two separate cases to be considered here). Let $E \to M$ be a vector bundle (again, smooth or holomorphic).
Denote by $\mathcal{O}(E)$ the sheaf of (smooth/holomorphic) sections of $E$. Let $C^{\infty}_M$ and $\mathcal{O}_M$ be the sheaves of smooth and holomorphic functions on $M$. Let $\Gamma(E)=\mathcal{O}(E)(M)$ be the (smooth/holomorphic) global sections of $E$.
I know that if everything is smooth, then for global sections we have: $\Gamma(f^*E)=\Gamma(E)\otimes_{C^{\infty}(M)}C^{\infty}(N)$. Here, $f^*E$ is the pullback bundle. My question is, does this extend to the level of sheaves?
In other words, is it true that:

$\mathcal{O}(f^*E)\cong \mathcal{O}(E)\otimes_{C^{\infty}_M}C^{\infty}_N$ as sheaves of $C^{\infty}_N$-modules?
$\mathcal{O}(f^*E)\cong \mathcal{O}(E)\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_M}\mathcal{O}_N$ as sheaves of $\mathcal{O}_N$-modules?

For (smooth) global sections, this looks plausible. However, defining tensor products of sheaves involves sheafification, so that makes me a little worried.
Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Indeed, the sheaf of sections of the pullback bundle is expressed via the tensor product of sheaves $f^{-1}(\mathcal{O}(E)) \otimes_{f^{-1}(C^{\infty}_M)} C^{\infty}_N$ (and simillarly in the holomorphic setting) ; I will later recall what $f^{-1}$ stands for. My answer is not a formal proof, but I hope it will provide the intuition behind the result.
One has to think of $f^*E$ as some kind of "minimal object" living above $N$, mapping to $E$, in a way compatible with $M$. This is by definition of the pullback:
\begin{array}{ccc}
f^*E & \rightarrow & E \\
\downarrow & & \downarrow \\
N & \xrightarrow{f} & M
\end{array}
Therefore it does make sense to think of the sheaf of sections of $f^*E$ as some minimal object with respect to sections $\mathcal{O}(E)$ and smooth/holomorphic maps on $N$. So let's see what kind of sections can be constructed from these two objects.
Let $U$ be an open subset of $M$, and $s$ is a section of $U$ to $E$, then $s \circ f : f^{-1}(U) \rightarrow E$ together with $id:f^{-1}(U) \rightarrow f^{-1}(U)$ induce a section from $f^{-1}(U)$, by definition of the topological pullback (which restricts to a pullback diagram above $U$). Now that we have such a section, we can always multiply it by a smooth/holomorphic function on $f^{-1}(U)$. By then patching together sums of sections obtained in this way, one finds more local/global sections of $f^*E$.
But this construction does not yield ALL local/global sections of $f^*E$, for one simple reason. Assume that $f^{-1}(U)$ is of the form $V_1 \cup V_2$ a disjoint union of open subsets. Then, instead of pulling back one section $s$ of $U$ to define a section of $V_1 \cup V_2$, you could also consider two sections $s_1$ and $s_2$ on $U$, pullback $s_1$ to $V_1$, and $s_2$ to $V_2$. In this way, one finds even more local/global sections of $f^*E$, and this time, after multiplying by smooth/holomorphic sections on open sets of $N$ and taking sums, we do find all sections of $f^* E$.
Summing up, we find that sections of $f^*E$ are exactly the maps which are locally (on $N$) obtained as sums of products of smooth/holomorphic functions with (pullbacks of) sections of $E$ on the image via $f$ (take some time to make sure this makes sense). This is nothing but the definition of the tensor product of sheaves: if $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{G}$ are sheaves on a variety $X$, then $\mathcal{F} \otimes_{C^{\infty}_X} \mathcal{G}$ is defined as the sheaf whose sections are locally obtained as sums of products of sections of $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{G}$.
As I said before, the sheaf of smooth sections of $f^* E$ is $f^{-1}(\mathcal{O}(E)) \otimes_{f^{-1}(C^{\infty}_M)} C^{\infty}_N$. The $f^{-1}$ has to be added to correct for one simple observation: if $V$ is an open subset of $N$, then $f(V)$ need not be open in $M$, so it does not quite make sense to speak of "sections on $f(V)$". Instead, we can make sense of sections on $W \subseteq f(V)$, and then take the limit as $W$ becomes smaller and smaller around $f(V)$: this is exactly what $f^{-1}$ of a sheaf does. If the map $f$ is open, the $f^{-1}$ can be removed.
Lastly, as a supplement I want to conclude by saying that because of what we have discussed, your description of the global sections of $f^*E$ for smooth maps and manifolds no longer holds in the holomorphic setting. This is because sections that are locally described as tensor products, when glued, need no longer be expressed via a tensor product. It is still true in the smooth case (see this answer) because of the existence of partitions of unity, which fails in the holomorphic case.
For instance, consider the open inclusion map $\mathbb{A}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^n$ of the affine complex space into the projective space, and consider the tautological line bundle on $\mathbb{P}^n$, $\mathcal{O}(-1)$ (not to be confused with the trivial line bundle). Its pullback is simply its restriction to $\mathbb{A}^n$, which is the trivial line bundle. The holomorphic global sections of the former are reduced to the zero section, while the holomorphic sections of the latter are all complex maps $\mathbb{C}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$.

Thanks for your answer! I have a few questions. Why do you take the tensor product over $f^{-1}(C^{\infty}_M)$, instead of just $C^{\infty}(N)$? Also, it's not clear to me why using the inverse image of sheaves would give us the desired answer, since it involves taking colimits. (Is something like "every section  on some possibly non-open subset can be extended to some open nbhd" used here?) Finally, can we deduce the claim about smooth global sections from the sheaf construction?

You shouldn't think too hard about the inverse image $f^{-1}$ of a sheaf. The idea is that you want to consider on $V \subseteq N$ smooth functions that are obtained as pullbacks of smooth functions on $f(V)$. But because $f(V)$ is not necessarily open, you can't just talk about $C^{\infty}_M(f(V))$. Instead, you consider smooth functions defined on open subsets of $M$ containing $f(V)$. That is basically all there is to $f^{-1}(C^{\infty}_N)(V)$, the colimit is just a formal way to expresss this construction ; I encourage you to get your head around this if it isn't quite clear.

The claim about global sections in the smooth case can be deduced from the sheaf construction, along with partitions of unity. See the answer I linked in my second to last paragraph.

I am not sure I follow your question about tensor product. The "base ring" in a tensor product is such that both objects being tensored are objects over this base ring. In this case, both sections of $E$ and smooth maps on $N$ can be acted on by smooth maps on $M$: by standard multiplication for the former, and by pullback and then multiplication in the latter.

Thanks for your answer. You're right. I forgot that $f^{-1}(\mathcal{O}(E))$ is a sheaf of $f^{-1}(\mathcal{O}_N)$-modules. The structure sheaf $\mathcal{O}_M$ looks irrelevant here.
